# Is there any software besides Simple Solver that will solve digital circuits given inputs/outputs?

Tags: boolean-logic, solver

All -

I have found something called "Simple Solver" located here:

http://home.roadrunner.com/~ssolver/syn.html

and you can download it here

http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Simple-Solver-Download-103308.html

My question is: Is Simple Solver the only one out there that solves digital circuits for you given inputs / outputs you want? Is there other software besides Simple Solver that will solve digital circuits?

Would appreciate all / any advise.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `Logic Friday 1`. This is an interactive tool so handle / solve boolean expressions defined as function table, expression or network of gates. Another cool tool is [BC2CNF](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/). Combined with a [SAT Solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) like [CryptoMinisat](http://www.msoos.org/cryptominisat2/), BC2CNF can be used to solve a boolean expression and find, which variable values actually fulfil the expression.