# bc2cnf is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: bc

bc`file and would like to convert it to a`.cnf` file, and hence i wanted to use bc2cnf.

However, it keeps giving me the error `'bc2cnf' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

There was only one package for download for `bc2cnf`.

Can anyone shed some light on this? as to how to use `bc2cnf`?

Comment: It doesn't look like `bc` is an appropriate tag (but it isn't entirely clear what is the correct tag; maybe `boolean` and `solver`?).  Look at [Boolean epression solver/simplifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546791/boolean-expression-solver-simplifier/14120120#14120120) or [Is there any software besides Simple Solver that will solve digital circuits given inputs/outputs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141942/is-there-any-software-besides-simple-solver-that-will-solve-digital-circuits-giv/14308886#14308886), found by a simple search on SO for `bc2cnf`.

Comment: there is this opensource to create cnf, and it is just called bc so i have no idea... and i am supposed to use bc for my courseware....

Comment: Well, [tag:bc] the tag is for the `bc` command which is an arbitrary precision calculator that is part of Unix (POSIX).  As such, it is not appropriate for other programs that are called `bc`, even though it is the logical spelling for it.  Presumably, you were also told where you can obtain the open source `bc` that creates cnf files.