# Is there any tool that implements a non-CNF SAT solver?

Tags: sat, sat-solvers, cnf

I need a SAT solver able to take as input not only CNF files but also normal txt files containing propositional clauses (written with only *and* *or* and *not*).

I couldn't find any. Could you please point out one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having searched carefully I have found limboole:
http://fmv.jku.at/limboole/.

It's really useful because it accepts any propositional logic formula and it can either compute whether it's valid or satisfiable.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/bcsat/), a commandline tool which translates Boolean "circuits" into `CNF`.

A circuit is a collection of Boolean expressions. The expressions can be used as input variables of other expressions.

Once you have the `CNF`, you can feed it into a [SAT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) like [cryptominisat](https://github.com/msoos/cryptominisat) or [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) to find solutions which satisfy your expression(s).

See related posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141942/is-there-any-software-besides-simple-solver-that-will-solve-digital-circuits-giv/14308886#14308886) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665864/tools-for-sat-grounding/28705215#28705215)

Another interesting innovation of Simon Felix is [SATInterface](https://github.com/deiruch/SATInterface). It allows to couple `C#` programs with SAT solvers [CaDiCaL](https://github.com/arminbiere/cadical) or [cryptominisat](https://github.com/msoos/cryptominisat).